# Django form validation with authenticated user as a field

Tags: django, forms, validation, authentication, modelform

Model:

```
class ProjectType(models.Model):
    project_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, help_text='Type of project', verbose_name='Project Type')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, help_text='Description of the main  purpose of the project', verbose_name='Project Type Description')
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
class Meta:
    ...
    unique_together = (('slug', 'owner'),('name', 'owner'))
```

I need a form to create/update ProjectType's. Please note the *owner* field - it is supposed to be current logged-in user. The question is how to ensure that constraints in the **unique_together** are validated correctly.

I do not want to show *owner* field on the form - it's the current user, so it should be set automatically by the system. But no matter how I try to do this, either validation does not work, or there are other errors.

Among approaches I tried (individually or in combination):

- Creating a hidden field in the related ModelField
- Defining *init* in ProjectTypeForm (in various ways), for example:

  ```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
      super(ProjectTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['owner'].initial = self.user
  ```
- Setting values in the view like:

  ```
  ...
  if request.method == 'POST':
      project_type = ProjectType(owner=request.user)
      form = ProjectTypeForm(request.POST, instance=project_type, user = request.user.pk) # also tries w/o pk
  ...
  ```
- Overriding clean() method of the form in various ways, along these lines:

  ```
  def clean(self):
      cleaned_data = super(ProjectTypeForm, self).clean()
      slug=cleaned_data.get('slug')
      owner = cleaned_data.get('owner')

      if slug:
          user = User.objects.get(pk=owner)
          ...
  ```

Many of these approaches are based on various answers found on stackoverflow.com. However, no matter what I try, I cannot find a way to accomplish what I need: (1) auto-setting of the owner field and (2) validation for uniqueness: owner/type_name and owner/type_slug. Typical errors I have is that (a) *owner* is not recognized as a User (it's treated as a PK), (b) incorrect validation (like lack of it or it misses the fact that it's the same record being edited, etc.), (c) owner is a required field.

For the record - if the *owner* is a regular field in the form, everything works as expected, but I cannot allow users to set the *owner* value.

Is there any, hopefully elegant, solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exclude the owner field from your form, and save the user in your form's init method - then you can use it to validate the form, eg

```
class ProjectTypeForm(...):
    ...
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def clean(self):
        user_projects = ProjectType.objects.filter(owner=self.user)
        if user_projects.filter(slug=self.cleaned_data['slug']):
            raise forms.ValidationError('...')
        elif user_projects.filter(name=self.cleaned_data['name']):
            raise forms.ValidationError('...')
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
```

Then in your view, do something like this when creating a new ProjectType:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProjectTypeForm(request.user, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ptype = form.save(commit=False)
        ptype.owner = request.user
        ptype.save()
```

You shouldn't need that to save existing ProjectType objects though.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not think it will work. The problem with what you suggest is that the "owner" (current user) is set after form.is_valid() is called - the django form validation has no knowledge of who the owner is. As a result, there is no way during validation to check constraints - uniqueness of owner/project type slug and project type name. What will happen: I will get a lower level exception (not caught) from the database engine - I've been there. But I am not a Django expert. So, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Another comment @Greg before I try - just for the record - the only way I see to solve this problem is actually to use "owner" on that form as it is supposed to be a ChoiceField but limit choices only to one user - the one who is currently logged in. I haven't tried that either but the theory seems sound. I will report on this as well - though I was hoping for a more elegant approach based on some Django trickery.

Comment: just tried your suggestion. Exactly as I expected: IntegrityError at /type-project-create/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PROJECT_TYPE_slug_owner_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (slug, owner_id)=(eee, 4) already exists.

Comment: I accept your solution (for same reasons I do not like my own - see above). But if someone wants to actually use the accepted solution beware - **it's mostly a conceptual approach**. A number of things should be taken care of to use it in practice. For example, things like self.cleaned_data['slug'] will throw KeyError if the slug value is not in the form (before the slug is validated as a required field). Bottom line - more coding in clean() and some logic change in it is needed before it's usable.

Comment: `clean()` is always called after all the other fields are validated, so if `slug` is a required field, it will always be there. Just saying. In any case, you're right, it's not production-ready code!

Comment: As you say it is always called. Because of this, if slug (or name) is not specified you will get KeyError with your code because slug will not be "there." Just try and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, one possible solution is essentially to go along with Django forms and use the *owner* field on the form. So, what I've done is modified **init** in this way:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['owner'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Owner*',
        queryset=User.objects.filter(username=user.username),
        help_text="Project types are unique to logged-in users who are set as their owners.",
        required=True,
        empty_label=None)
```

Basically, what it does it is still using ChoiceField but sets it to one option - current user. In addition, empty_label=None ensures that there is no "empty" choice. The effect is (since username is unique) that current user name appears visible and is the only choice in the otherwise dropdown list with more choices.

In the view I follow this approach:

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    project_type = ProjectType()
    form = ProjectTypeForm(request.user,request.POST, instance=project_type,)
    if form.is_valid():
        project_type.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_types'))
else:
    form = ProjectTypeForm(request.user)
...
```

Basically, that's it - validation of unique constraints (and the whole thing) works like a charm.

Do I like this solution? No. I consider it a hack (ironically, even if it goes along with standard Django approaches). But it requires something that is totally unnecessary. One benefit of this approach is that it clearly communicates to the current user that s/he is set as the project type owner. But even with this in mind I would rather show a message (instead of a field) that *Current user X will be set as the owner of the project type being created*. **So, if someone has a better solution, please submit it to illustrate the full power and flexibility of Django.**